# Characterization of finite measure on $\left(\mathbb R,B(\mathbb R)\right)$

Tags: measure-theory

Here in question ,$B(\mathbb {R})$ denotes Borel $\sigma$ algebra. By $F$ i mean function $F:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$. And we say $F$ has property 1 (p1) if it is right continuous and non decreasing . and has property 2 (p2) if it is bounded , $\lim_{{x}\to{-\infty}} F(x)=0$ and property 1.and  $m$ denotes measure on $(\mathbb R,B(\mathbb R) )$. and we say $m$ is Baire measure if it is finite on all bounded Borel sets.

Now every Baire measure $m$ corresponds to class $A_m$ of real functions (unique upto constant) with property 1  , such that $$ \text{for  each}~ F \in A_m , \text{we have} ~~m(a,b]=F(b)-F(a) ~\text{ for every}~ a,b \in \mathbb R , a<b   ~~~~~  \ldots (1)$$.
Moreover if Baire measure $m$ is finite ( $m(\mathbb R)$<$\infty$) ,then it corresponds to unique  function F ( usually called CDF) which has property 2 . since all finite measure are Baire measure result (1) certainly true for finite measure.

Now my claim is : Let $m$ baire measure and $ A_m$ is corresponding class of functions .then

> m is finite measure iff there exist $F \in A_m$ with property 2 .( in $A_m$ all functions has already property 1).

Now the only if part is easy , for "if" part

suppose there is $ F\in A_m$ with property 2 . since $ F\in A_m$ ,we have $m(a,b]=F(b)-F(a)~ $for every $a,b \in \mathbb R , a<b $

Now using Extra properties namely $F$ bounded and $\lim_{{x}\to{-\infty}} F(x)=0$, we prove $m$ is finite measure whose  CDF  is $F$.

For $x\in \mathbb R$ and  $a_n\to-\infty ~~, a_n \leq x$ and $a_n$ is decresing,and By continuity of measure  ,we have $$ m(-\infty,x] = m\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^{+\infty} (a_n,x]\right) = \lim_{{n} \to {\infty}} m(a_n,x] =  \lim_{{n} \to {\infty}} (F(x)-F(a_n)) =F(x) ~~\text{as}, ~\lim_{{x}\to{-\infty}} F(x)=0$$

Now i dont know How to use Boundedness of $F$ to proceed further to prove $m$ is finite.

How can i do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $F$ is bounded, so that there is some constant $C < \infty$ with $F(x) \le C$ for all $x$.  By property 2, we also have $F(x) \ge 0$ for all $x$.  So for any interval $(a,b]$, we have $m((a,b]) = F(b) - F(a) \le C - 0 = C$.

Fix sequences $a_n, b_n$ where $a_n \searrow -\infty$ and $b_n \nearrow +\infty$.  Then $\mathbb{R} = \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty (a_n, b_n]$ as an increasing union, so
$m(\mathbb{R}) = \lim_{n \to \infty} m((a_n, b_n])$.  But since $m((a_n, b_n]) \le C$ for every $n$, the same is true of the limit.  Hence $m(\mathbb{R}) \le C < \infty$.

Comment: Here $m(\mathbb{R}) = \lim_{n \to \infty} m((a_n, b_n])$ is true if $a_n$ and $b_n$ are arbitrary that converges to $-\infty$ and $\infty$ respectively ? or we need $a_n$ to be decreasing and $b_n$ is increaing

Comment: @SureshKumar: Sure, let's take $a_n$ decreasing and $b_n$ increasing, since then we can apply continuity of measure directly.  I edited the answer.  The proof would still work without that assumption, since $m(\mathbb{R}) =\lim_{n \to \infty} m((a_n, b_n])$ is actually still true for arbitrary $a_n \to -\infty$, $b_n \to +\infty$, but it would take some extra steps to justify.

Comment: Can you give some Hints how can i show for arbitrary $a_n \to -\infty$ and $b_n \to \infty$ ?

Comment: @SureshKumar: Maybe proof by contradiction is quickest.  Suppose $m(\mathbb{R}) = \infty$.  By continuity there exists some $R$ with $m((-R, R]) > C$.  If $a_n \to -\infty$ and $b_n \to \infty$, then for some large enough $k$ we have $a_k \le -R$ and $b_k \ge R$, and this should lead you to a contradiction.